# xTube - - why can't I access it using TOR?

Tags: blocked-services

I run an adult business and when traveling overseas I like to cover my base since not all countries are adult content friendly. Lately I have been having trouble connecting to xtube.com. Can someone please tell me what is the issue in this case?

Comment: Most likely, xTube is blocking Tor. At any rate, if you wouldn't do it over your personal connection, maybe you shouldn't be doing it over someone else's.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vpn as opposed to tor. I use a throwaway one like Vigilantium while traveling. https://vigilantium.com

Answer (score 0):

it will be a VPN to fit a proper solution slot in your case. You can use Tor to connect to your homeplace-running hidden service for OpenVPN - so it will be completely private